# Проблема с выполнением запроса из одного проекта Laravel в другой с использованием docker-контейнеров

Tags: php, laravel, docker, postman

Есть проект А (Laravel) - он поднят при помощи docker-контейнера, и делает post-запрос (Guzzle) на проекта B.
Есть проект B (Laravel Sail), который обрабатывает этот запрос.
Они оба расположены на одной машине.
Ошибка следующая:
[image: Сама ошибка]

Вот сам запрос из проекта A:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: У вас ведь в сообщение Laravel написана ошибка. Как вы из одного контейнера отправляете запрос в другой? Вы уверены, что два контейнера с Laravel знают о существовании друг друга?

Comment: Простите, не совсем пойму что вы имеете ввиду?

Я пробовал добавить контейнер B в сеть проекта А @zerxa

Comment: У вас проект А видит проект Б? Попробуйте проверить проект А написав в index.php файле простой запрос через file_get_content на проект Б (к примеру).

Comment: Чтобы иметь возможность обращаться по доменному имени нужно чтобы контейнер понимал куда ему обращаться за его "переводом" в IP адрес. Это на Linux контейнерах делается через [/etc/hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151981/local-hostnames-for-docker-containers).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит о том, что у вас нет такого адреса.

Попробуйте в Docker узнать IP контейнера с помощью команды:

```
docker ps
```

вы получите все свои запущенные контейнеры, далее найдите нужный и скопируйте его ID.

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' [ID контейнера]
```

Вывод в консоль покажет IP адрес нужного контейнера по которому ваши проекты Docker смогут общаться "между собой".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за уделенное время.
Но, к сожалению, это не помогло
При указании ip-адреса postman просто зависает на sending request и всё.

Comment: Так вы ведь писали про Laravel. Postman и ваша локальная машина само собой не увидит IP адресов, которые используются внутри Docker. Postman должен видеть внешний Docker IP адрес и порт

Comment: Разницы нет: делаю я запрос из postman или из приложения, исход один - ответ не приходит.
Спасибо ещё раз за ответ.